# Cron: running cron every 1 second?

Tags: linux, cron

How can I run cron every 1 second? there's only minutes option by default

Comment: I *hope* your job itself completes inside 1 second? :)

Comment: Cron every second? Are you sure!? It's crazy! :)

Comment: it's just a small script

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let cron start the job one time, the first time. Put the program in an infinite loop, sleep() for 1 second at the end of each loop. like this, in C:

```
  int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
      while (1) {
        // do the work
        sleep(1000);
      }
  }
```

Could that work?

Comment: Yes. great solution. Can you help me doing it with bash?

Comment: For a bash answer, please ask a new question.

Comment: Why bother starting it from cron?

Comment: I'd start it from cron if I wanted it to run starting at a certain time of day, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Cron executes stuff every minute.  Use a script:

```
while :
do
    sleep 1
    some_command || break
done
```

or in one line:

```
while : ; do sleep 1 ; some_command || break ; done
```

This will wait 1 second in between each execution, so if your command takes .75 seconds to run, then this script will kick it off every 1.75 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can't with cron, because 1 minute is **THE** minimum time interval available. You'd have to run a script that fires up 60 other scripts, with delays of 0 to 59 seconds, or a single script which re-runs itself 60 times.

But at that point, why not just run a single script outside of cron which does sleep(1) in a loop?